# How to encode url by using preg_replace function in php?

Tags: php, preg-replace, encode

I have follow this code:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<a href="http:\/\/domain.com\/view\/img\/(.*)">TEXT<\/a>/', '<a href="http://mydomain.com/get.php?url='.base64_encode('{$1}').'">TEXT</a>', $content);
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: And this isn't working... how?

Comment: **HOW** is it not working? If it was working, you wouldn't be here. So tell us what it SHOULD be doing, what it IS doing, and what you've TRIED to do to fix it.

Comment: It could encode inside on base64('{$1}'). For example,

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, I think you have to scape the ". Try with:

```
$content = preg_replace('/<a href=\"http:\/\/domain.com\/view\/img\/(.*)\">TEXT<\/a>/', '<a href="http://mydomain.com/get.php?url='.base64_encode('{$1}').'">TEXT</a>', $content);
```

Comment: It could encode inside on base64('{$1}'). For example, I have url http://domain.com/view/img/a26256f2f6/ and I want to encode the whole url or a26256f2f6 value of url http://domain.com/view/img/. When I run above code, It could encode a26256f2f6 value, so It encoded into http://mydomain.com/get.php?url={a26256f2f6}. How to remove {a26256f2f6} into a26256f2f6 ?

Comment: No, you don't have to escape quotes in a different-quoted string. e.g. `'"a"'` and `"'a'"` are both perfectly acceptable. but if it was `'<a href='...'`, then yes, you would have to escape.

Comment: $content = str_replace("{","",$content);

Comment: and $content = str_replace("}","",$content);